# Can a custom mapping of my keyboard protect me from a keylogger?

Tags: security, keyboard, keylogger

Pure theoretical question here : how a custom mapping of the keyboard may impact the effectiveness of a keylogger on my machine? Will this have any impact?

Imagine me, when I should type a password, just change to my new custom mapping and then type it. Should that be a protection against a keylogger? I imagine that an attacker would just have to go look for the configuration file to understand.

I have know nothing about keyloggers so excuse me if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

A custom mapping of the keyboard *shouldn't* be used as protection against a keylogger. Reason being, the usage of different mappings on your keyboard does not mean a different password; you still have to type in the same password (characters, numbers, etc.), even with custom mappings.